# Is it okay to parallelize memory allocation delete with openmp? (c++)

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, openmp, kill

```
int **something = new int *[N];
for(int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    something[n] = new int[M];

#pragma omp parallel for
for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    delete[] something[n];
delete[] something;
```

Can I parallelize a delete process like this?

OOM killer of Linux killed my process after quite big number of loops. I tried to figure out where the memory is leaking, but I could not find where. I am not sure if these for loop delete process worked well or not.

Comment: But why?  Is parallelizing this operation save enough time to overcome the setup and takedown?

Comment: Is your heap lock-free?  It'd be ironic if the heap had a mutex, which would serialize the operations.

Comment: Ashamed to admit it just took 20 years to realized the joke at the heart of Battledroid commander OOM-9's name.

Comment: *OOM killer of Linux killed my process after quite big number of loops.*  How will parallelizing `delete` calls help with that?

Comment: Maybe you need to investigate your virtual memory usage and increase the size of your swap.

Comment: Sorry for my poor confusing question. I just signed up at stack overflow and started programming just a month ago. Even not an English user.
I made a project, ran it for ~100000 loops, and it was killed. So I tried to figure out where the memory leak happened, and had doubts about this part of code. I didn't know that parallelizing deallocation doesn't really help.

Comment: The use of `new` counts as not-good C++. Why aren't you using standard containers, which are much more memory safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is generally okay. The standard (g)libc heap must be thread-safe; otherwise, it'd be impossible to write threaded programs at all. It's also fine to allocate a buffer on one thread and free it on another.

Parallelizing heap allocations won't give you much of a speed-up, but I suspect you're asking not because you want to speed up (de-)allocation, but rather because you have some other parallel code that happens to allocate and free some buffers.

To find your leak, try running your program with valgrind.

Additionally, consider calling `malloc_trim(0);` after freeing large amounts of memory. This makes glibc release unused memory back to the operating system, instead of holding onto all of it for later allocations.

Comment: Parallelizing the allocations would actually help since different threads have different memory arenas. So this can be parallelized. I just tested this and found a factor 4 on my system. Just parallelizing the deallocation will not help since every thread will compete for the lock to the one arena where everything was allocated

Comment: @Homer512 *Parallelizing the allocations would actually help since different threads have different memory arenas.*  Only if the allocations aren't large enough to either be replaced with `mmap()` or cause repeated calls to `[s]brk()` to get more memory.  Either of those are going to require new VM pages to be created and mapped, neither of which can be multithreaded.

Comment: @AndrewHenle True, it is size-dependent

Comment: I haven't expected these fast feedbacks from lots of users since I am first to here. Learned a lot, and gonna try these things you've mentioned while debugging.